# Convert RGB image into 3D Model in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem

I'm new to qgis and working with maps in general.

I have this image that is technically elevation data (but jpeg with no data points)from Dronedeploy.

I imported this image as a raster mesh layer - it created 3 bands, Red Green Blue
[image]

Blue the lowest elevation, and red the highest.

However, I read that to extract the elevation and convert this into a DEM, I need to do a raster calculation and I'm only able to select one band out of the three there.

[image]

Either can I convert these 3 bands into a single band so that the DEM can be created or can I add all three in my raster calculation or is there another way to convert these color values into elevation information within QGIS?

Update for clarification: This is what I want/trying to create for the end result.
[image]

Band blue I think?
[image]

Comment: Sorry, that's not "technically elevation data".  It's a rendered image.  It's suitable for viewing and visualising only.  You need the [GeoTIFF (Raw Elevation Values - DEM) format](https://help.dronedeploy.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500004964622-Data-Export-Formats)

Comment: I understand. I want to use it for visualizing only - to create a 3d elevation model based on the differences in the colors in the pixels

Comment: I've updated the question to make sense of what I meant here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably easier to download a DEM. If you are ok with ~30 m resolution you can download [Aster v.3](https://www.earthdata.nasa.gov/news/new-aster-gdem) from [here](https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search)

Comment: 30m or 30mi? This is a very small piece of land and from what I was told, the google earth data on this is super outdated or does not exist. Hence, we captured it with a drone.

Comment: Can you just show us the band3 (blue)? Sometime, in such RGB files, X_coord is band1, Y_coord is band2 and Z_value is band3. If it is the case, just use raster calculation with 'elevation@3' and you’ll get your DEM. But I’m not sure in your case… it seems a « render image » as user2856 said!

Comment: I've added band blue, I think. Please check

Comment: Aster is ~30 meters resolution.

Comment: Ok, it is just a render image as I can see!

Comment: "to create a 3d elevation model" isn't visualising only, you need the raw elevation values from somewhere to drape over.

Comment: I want the raw elevation (not the actual elevation, but the difference in heights) between a red pixel and blue pixel to be somehow extracted from the color ramp.